# RelativeLayout is not drawing correctly with coordinator layout android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, coordinator-layout

I have coded a simple fragment which couple of text views and a button , all in a RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".fragments.TutorialFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tuto_title"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/tutorial_title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tuto_msg"
        style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tuto_title"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/tutorial_txt"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="@string/next"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This fragment displays great on the StudioDesigner , however when executing the code the title is missing[image: AVD Running]

The Activity Layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
tools:context="com.crocodil.software.a1ccalc.A1CActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

It looks as the fragment calculates its available space before the toolbar is placed...

This is the Screen as I see it in the designer

[image: Designer]

Thanks for any hints

Comment: That is correct ofcourse. However its annoying that the designer displays the screen differently the AVD or a real device. It makes the debugging much harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the FrameLayout is behind the toolbar, the main way of adding a view within the coordinator layout that has a toolbar is to either set a `margin` or add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the Framelayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
tools:context="com.crocodil.software.a1ccalc.A1CActivity">

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this attribute

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

and put it on the FrameLayout fragment_container.